# Something wrong with NDK_MODULE_PATH in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

This is my problem:

```
Android NDK: C:/Users/XNOTE/Desktop/android-master/Q//jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'botan' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
C:/Users/XNOTE/Desktop/android-master/Q//jni/Android.mk:60: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

I keep all files at: `C:\Users\XNOTE\Desktop\android_modules_sources`
and this is my build.sh file:

```
#! /bin/sh

export NDK_MODULE_PATH=$NDK_MODULE_PATH:`pwd`/..:`pwd`/../sdk:$Q/android_modules:$Q/android_modules_sources
env | grep NDK

if [[ $1 = "clean" ]]; then
    echo "clean"
    ndk-build clean
else
    echo "build"
    ndk-build V=1
fi

#ndk-build V=1
#ndk-build clean
```

What is wrong?